# Motivation for Martingales

Tags: probability, martingales

Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\, \mathcal{F},\,(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}},\, P)$, a **martingale** is defined to be a sequence of $L^1$ random variables $X_{n}: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
  E[X_n | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = X_{n-1}.
$$
In many books, it is said that the motivation of this definition is to model the wealth of a gambler playing a fair game. For example, suppose $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots$ represent coin tosses which are independent and give 1 dollar for the player if heads and takes him 1 dollar if tails. The gambler's wealth after $n$ coin tosses is then given by the radom variable $S_n = X_1 + \ldots + X_n$. The sequence $S_n$ is a martingale, considered the filtration given by $\mathcal{F}_n = \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, for
$$
  E[S_{n}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = E[X_1 + \ldots + X_n | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = X_1 + \ldots + X_{n-1} + E[X_n|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}] = X_1 + \ldots + X_{n-1} + E[X_n] = X_1 + \ldots + X_{n-1} = S_{n-1}, 
$$
where we used the fact that $X_n$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ and has expectation zero. We see that $S_n$ is a martingale, as we would guess, once one cannot hope to make more money by tossing a coin just because one knows the previous results of other coin tosses. Intuitively, this definition and example makes sense, but when we try to analize it rigorously, we have some issues:

1. Why are the $S_n$ random variables? I mean, what space is the domain of the funcion?
2. Well, one could naturally think that $S_n$ is either defined in $\Omega = \{H, T\}$ or in $\Omega^{n}$.
3. Intuitivelly, it makes no sense for $S_n$ to be defined in $\Omega$, for then its only possible values would be $n$ ou $-n$.
4. Mathematically, it makes no sense for $S_n$ to be defined in $\Omega^n$, for each $S_n$ would have a different domain, each of them different from the domain of the $X_n$, and then we would not be able to talk about the filtration, condintional expectations, etc.

The question therefore is: how to find a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where we can define the sequence of coin tosses $X_n$, the sequence of the gambler's wealth $S_n$, consider the filtration generated by $X_n$ and prove that, besides modeling nicely the gamble situation, $S_n$ is indeed a martingale, accordingly to our previous definition?

Comment: $S_n$ is a random variable as a sum of random variables. All random variables mentioned in your question are defined on the same (filtered) probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, which we don't need to explicit. Don't you make a confusion between the domain and the range of the random variables?

Comment: Why we don't need do explicit the filtered probability space? I am not making a confusion between the domain and range. The range is clearly $\mathbb{Z}$. But it is really weird for me to assume that the $X_n$ and $S_n$ are defined on te same (filtered) probability space without knowing wish space is it. How can I define the functions if I dont know their domain?